# How competitive are postdocs in math?

Tags: postdocs, job-search

I applied to a lot of places (about 80) and only got 1 offer. It makes me worried that when it's time to apply for jobs again I won't get any offers. I would like to know if such a circumstance is typical. A postdoc colleague of mine told me, "At least you *have* a postdoc." We both had a tough time in the current job market.

Comment: The 80:1 ratio isn't necessarily very informative, because they're not iid trials.  You applied for 80, but most likely, there were some small number of those for which you were always a much better fit, because of a close match in research interests to someone at the other end.

Comment: Anecdotal, so this is a comment rather than an answer, but I've known plenty of people who only got a single postdoc offer coming out of math grad school. So I would say your experience with the postdoc job market is fairly typical.

Comment: I also got one postdoc offer out of a lot (10 years ago), and it was the one that all along seemed most likely.

Comment: If you edited the question to ask about a particular measure of competitiveness, than it would be better. You might also want to specify the countries where you were applying.

Comment: To echo the other comments, postdoc is also the level where it starts to be more and more about connections. If you know the potential new boss and have already talked with him about mathematics or even worked with him on something before, you are much more likely to get hired than if you blanketly spam every advertised opening. I've seen many cases where the ratio has been effectively 1:1 (no cancelled fraction), because of that.

Comment: I assume it is true in other fields also, but in mathematics the job market is very cyclic. It depends on many things including the general state of the economy and the perceived needs of scientific progress among politicians. In a few years it might be quite different. But some of the questions on this site seem to say that right now there is more supply then there is demand in math. Work to be ready when/if that changes.

Comment: Another thing to consider: a PhD means you are *highly* specialized.  I bet at least half the positions were not even good matches, where the focus of the work would be different enough that you wouldn't actually enjoy working on it or you'd have to invest a lot of extra work to really contribute.  In industry, the nuance of your specialization would be valued less and you'd probably get more offers based on your general knowledge of advanced mathematics.